# Почему в ответ на запрос в Postman получаю пустой объект?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Оправляю в Postman запрос на `http://localhost:5000/api/ads/getAdverts` . В ответ получаю пустой объект.

Тело запроса ниже:

```js
[
    "5fe999d60b26ea24e8423660",
    "5fe9cf048cf16b2360bc9b49"
]
```

```js
// getArrAdverts
adsRouter.get('/getAdverts', async (req,res) => {
  const adsIdArr = req.body;
  const result = []
  adsIdArr.forEach(async (ad) => {
    const selectedAd = await AdModel.findById(ad)
    result.push(selectedAd)
  })
  

  if(!result) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: 'Ads not found' });
    return
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(result);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В `get`-запросе нет `body`, но есть `query`. Вы показываете обработчик именно `get`-запроса.
2. Нельзя так использовать асинхронные вызовы внутри `.forEach`.

`forEach` - выполнит последовательно и синхронно свои колбеки и не будет ждать завершения асинхронных задач, задачи будут запущены, но выполнение пойдёт дальше к отправке ответа.

Делайте так (`map` создаст массив `Promise`, а `await Promise.all` дождётся их выполнения):

```
adsRouter.YOUR_HTTP_METHOD_NAME('/getAdverts', async (req,res) => {
  const adsIdArr = HERE_YOUR_ADS_IDX;

  const result = await Promise.all(
    adsIdArr.map((ad) => AdModel.findById(ad))
  );

  res.status(200).json(result);
})
```

Comment: обратите внимание, что вам вовсе не нужен findById, тут одним вызовом find можно достать все записи